# Use pandas to convert csv to json for plotting two series instead of one in highcharts highstock graph

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, highcharts

Problem is to show two series, for adjusted high and adjusted low, in a highcharts highstock graph similar to the following which shows only one series:

[image: Highstock chart with one series for adjusted high]

Links to similar Highstock question and JSFiddle:

https://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=40964&p=142595&hilit=multiple+series#p142595

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xqgv2b4k/

Below are my working files used to produce the graph above.

sample.csv (input)

```
DATE,ADJ_HIGH,ADJ_LOW
2018-04-27,164.33,160.630
2018-04-30,167.26,161.840
2018-05-01,169.20,165.270
2018-05-02,177.75,173.800
2018-05-03,177.50,174.441
```

csv_to_json_testing.py

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

input_file = 'sample.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(input_file, usecols=[0,1,2], parse_dates=['DATE'], date_parser = pd.to_datetime) #  keep_default_na = False

with open('overflow.txt', 'w') as f:
    df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 6
    print(file=f)
    print('DATE, ADJ_HIGH (json)', file=f)
    print(file=f)
    print(df[['DATE','ADJ_HIGH']].tail(5).to_json(orient='values'), file=f)
    print(file=f)
    print('DATE, ADJ_LOW (json)', file=f)
    print(file=f)
    print(df[['DATE','ADJ_LOW']].tail(5).to_json(orient='values'), file=f)
    print(file=f)
    print('DATE, ADJ_HIGH, ADJ_LOW (json)', file=f)
    print(file=f)
    print(df[['DATE','ADJ_HIGH','ADJ_LOW']].tail(5).to_json(orient='values'), file=f)
```

overflow.txt (output)

```
DATE, ADJ_HIGH (json)

[[1524787200000,164.33],[1525046400000,167.26],[1525132800000,169.2],[1525219200000,177.75],[1525305600000,177.5]]

DATE, ADJ_LOW (json)

[[1524787200000,160.63],[1525046400000,161.84],[1525132800000,165.27],[1525219200000,173.8],[1525305600000,174.441]]

DATE, ADJ_HIGH, ADJ_LOW (json)

[[1524787200000,164.33,160.63],[1525046400000,167.26,161.84],[1525132800000,169.2,165.27],[1525219200000,177.75,173.8],[1525305600000,177.5,174.441]]
```

sample.json (DATE, ADJ_HIGH)

```
[[1524787200000,164.33],[1525046400000,167.26],[1525132800000,169.2],[1525219200000,177.75],[1525305600000,177.5]]
```

highstock_test.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Chart
    </title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('sample.json', function (data) {
    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'XYZ Stock Price'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'XYZ',
            data: data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 350px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I store `sample.json` and `highstock_test.html` in a folder, then open the html file in a browser, I get the highstock graph shown above for one series. My challenge is to properly populate and format `sample.json` with DATE, ADJ_HIGH, and ADJ_LOW data, and to edit `highstock_test.html` so the plot properly renders two series instead of one. Would like to use the method that is easiest to understand and that could also be adapted to serve charts from a flask application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display two series you need to create two series configuration objects:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: data1
    }, {
        data: data2
    }]
});
```

If you want to use two separate JSON data, you will only have to assign the right values: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fho6na5r/, but to use only one, you need to convert it to data structure required by Highcharts:

```
var data = [
        [1524787200000, 164.33, 160.63],
        [1525046400000, 167.26, 161.84],
        [1525132800000, 169.2, 165.27],
        [1525219200000, 177.75, 173.8],
        [1525305600000, 177.5, 174.441]
    ],
    dataS1 = [],
    dataS2 = [];

data.forEach(function(el) {
    dataS1.push([el[0], el[1]]);
    dataS2.push([el[0], el[2]]);
});

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: dataS1
    }, {
        data: dataS2
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gv7mph8x/6/

Comment: Thanks for a very good answer. Questions re. using getJSON approach: `$.getJSON('sample.json', function (data) {`. What goes in `sample.json`? Must dataS1 and dataS2 be defined there or can it be done separately in javascript? What goes in javascript to push values into dataS1, dataS2, per that approach? Thanks in advance if you understand my questions and can provide further information.

Comment: Hi SystemTheory, Your JSON structure is fine, you just need to convert it to Highcharts series structure. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a1hus8qn/